# How to get the success message after clicking on submit button

Tags: javascript, php

I have my code where it should show a success message after submitting (click on add) but for some reason this success message is showing all the time even if I don't add anything, it is just showing on the top of the page.the problem is if I removed the message that is below if statement, the message will not show. the action is working fine it is just the success message. Can you please see what is the problem?

Add.php

```
<?php
include('header.php');
?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../validation/dist/css/bootstrapValidator.css"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../../validation/dist/js/bootstrapValidator.js"></script>
  <!-- =============================================== -->
  <?php
    include('../../form.php');
    $frm=new formBuilder;
  ?>
  <!-- =============================================== -->

  <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
    <section class="content-header">
      <h1>
        Add Coming Soon Movie
      </h1>
      <?php
      if(isset($_SESSION['add']))
      {?>
      <div class="alert alert-success">
  <strong>Success!</strong> News added successfully..
</div>
<?php
}?>
      <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li><a href="index.php"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
        <li class="active">Add Coming Soon Movie</li>
      </ol>
    </section>

    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">

      <!-- Default box -->
      <div class="box">
        <div class="box-body">
            <form action="process_add_news.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form1">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Movie name</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control"/>
                <?php $frm->validate("name",array("required","label"=>"Movie Name")); // Validating form using form builder written in form.php ?>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                 <label class="control-label">Type</label>
                <input type="text" name="type" class="form-control">
                <?php $frm->validate("type",array("required","label"=>"Type","regexp"=>"text")); // Validating form using form builder written in form.php ?>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Release Date</label>
                <input type="date" name="date" class="form-control"/>
                <?php $frm->validate("date",array("required","label"=>"Release Date")); // Validating form using form builder written in form.php ?>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Description</label>
                 <input type="text" name="description" class="form-control">
                 <?php $frm->validate("description",array("required","label"=>"Description")); // Validating form using form builder written in form.php ?>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label">Images</label>
              <input type="file"  name="attachment" class="form-control" placeholder="Images">
               <?php $frm->validate("attachment",array("required","label"=>"Image")); // Validating form using form builder written in form.php ?>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Trailer Youtube Link</label>
                <input type="text" name="video" class="form-control"/>
                <?php $frm->validate("video",array("label"=>"Image","max"=>"500")); // Validating form using form builder written in form.php ?>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-success">Add Movie</button>
              </div>
        </form>
        </div>
        <!-- /.box-footer-->
      </div>
      <!-- /.box -->

    </section>
    <!-- /.content -->
  </div>
  <?php
include('footer.php');
?>
<script>
        <?php $frm->applyvalidations("form1");?>
    </script>
```

**processToAdd.php**:

```
<?php
    include('../../config.php');
    extract($_POST);
       $uploaddir = '../Coming-soon/';
      $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['attachment']['name']);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'],$uploadfile);
    $flname="Coming-soon/".basename($_FILES["attachment"]["name"]);
    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO tbl_news values (NULL,'$name','$type','$date','$description','$flname','$video')");
    $_SESSION['add']=1;
    header('location:add_movie_news.php');
?>
```

Comment: use session like $_SESSION['success_flag'] = true;

Comment: it is already there

Comment: I think you miss `session_start()` at the top line

Answer (score 1):

I try this and found that, you need to start session

You just need to add `session_start();`

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_REQUEST['submit_btn']))
    {
       $name = $_POST["names"];
       $_SESSION['add'] = $name;
       print_r($_SESSION);
    }
?>
<html>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>
    <?php
      if(isset($_SESSION['add'])) {
    ?>
        <div class="">
            <strong>Success!</strong> News added successfully..
        </div>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
    <form action="" method="POST">
       <input type="text" name="names" id="names">
       <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit_btn">
    </form>
    <script>

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: sorry i didnt get that

Comment: You have to write session_start(); in both files Add.php and proccessToAdd.php

Comment: I use your code as example and try to make a simple demo, Please find my another answer, Hope that will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the issue is the line `if(isset($_SESSION['add']))`. So as long as `$_SESSION['add']` is set the you have to see the message. Its either you unset it immediately after the message and reset it again on each button click or if the button you click is named 'submit', just use

```
if(isset($_POST['add'])){
   //output message here
}
```

Comment: that removed the message which is good but when i add the movie it doesnt show the success message

Answer (score 0):

I try your code as example and remove validation and extra things

I also redirect Add.php to processToAdd.php and then again redirect processToAdd.php to Add.php

Please have a look and try this.

Hope this will resolve your problem.

**Add.php**:

```
<?php
  session_start();
?>
<!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
  <section class="content-header">
    <h1>
      Add Coming Soon Movie
    </h1>
    <?php
      if(isset($_SESSION['add'])) {
    ?>
      <div class="alert alert-success">
        <strong>Success!</strong> News added successfully..
      </div>
    <?php
      }
    ?>

    </section>

    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">

      <!-- Default box -->
      <div class="box">
        <div class="box-body">
            <form action="processToAdd.php" method="post" enctype="" id="form1">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Movie name</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control"/>

              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Add Movie</button>
              </div>
        </form>
        </div>
        <!-- /.box-footer-->
      </div>
      <!-- /.box -->

    </section>
    <!-- /.content -->
</div>
```

**processToAdd.php**:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    extract($_POST);
    $_SESSION['add']=1;
    header('location:add.php');
?>
```

Comment: Is this useful to you? @wolter